# Есть ли лучший система сборки чем Make?

Tags: linux

У меня был исходный код одной программы и я хотел собрать его и для сборки я  установил **build-essential** всё успешна установилась но когда я вводил команду: **./configure** ! Там у меня выдал ошибку о том что нет определённая утилита ! Я установил несколько утилит которых не хватала но после этого **make** выдаёт ошибку что не установлен тот пакет и я устал и бросил **make**! Мне бы хотелось узнать **есть ли** какой нибудь **система сборки** который **"из коробки"** будет работать, не выдасть никаких ошибок вовремя сборки програм и не потребует никаких дополнительных утилит?

Comment: вопрос. А откуда система сборки будет брать необходимые зависимости?

Comment: С make я устал, он брал у меня много времени за скачивание и установки потребующих ему утилит. Я хотел узнать есть ли система сборки который сказал все недостающих и необходимых утилит и не выдал ошибку вовремя сборки.

Comment: откуда система сборки должна знать что Вам нужно и где это брать? Точно также можно спросит "Хочу систему, чтобы все нужные МНЕ программы были из коробки".

Comment: как "откуда система сборки должна знать" он же не спрашивает мистические утилиты !

Comment: нда уж. программа *make* - это **вообще** не "система сборки".

Comment: И чем, собственно, провинился тут make? То, что необходимо для сборки и выполнения (разные наборы вещей, обращаю внимание), должно быть описано в документации к устанавливаемому. Если автору хватает времени, он может даже собрать команды для менеджеров пакетов нескольких дистрибутивов, которые установят это. Но, повторюсь, make тут совершенно ни при чём и любая его замена вас совершенно не спасёт.

Comment: Немного оффтоп, но у меня из глаз кровь пошла от стиля описания. "100 бал егэ па рускаму", не иначе.

Comment: @donRumata, не для всех русский — родной язык; и в этом нет ничего плохого... если так коробит, то есть кнопка «править».

Comment: @donRumata как-раз таки у человека нормальное знание русского языка, учитывая то, что русский - для него не родной. Другое дело, когда носители языка делают ошибки по типу "не собираеться", и так далее...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как уже сказали, искать «замену make» — не корректно. Искать зависимости и устанавливать их — абсолютно не его задача (хотя в некоторых проектах она решается его средствами, но это обычно костыль, который разработчик оставляет для себя или для менее грамотных пользователей).

С другой  стороны есть много различных решений, как упростить поиск/установку/сборку зависимостей... Почти все они основаны на скриптах написанных для них другими людьми и ни одна из них не даёт гарантию, что что-то при сборке не пойдёт не так и не произойдёт ошибки т.к. *nix системы и возможности по их конфигурации крайне разнообразны.

Перечислить их все — дело не благодарное, но вот некоторые (далеко не все) инструменты достойные упоминания с которых можно начать вникать в тему:

- `apt-get build-dep` — простой способ избыточной установки зависимостей для пакетов входящих в пост-дебиан дистрибутивы.
- `gentoo-prefix` — предоставляет возможность сборки ПО со всеми зависимостями в отдельном префиксе.
- `homebrew` — менеджер пакетов происхождением из MacOS, сам я не вникал, что это, но слышал некоторые хвалебные отзывы.